# How to access a specific property within a nested but fixed structure of arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my array

```
let result=[
  { lon: -122.08, lat: 37.39 },
  [ { id: 800, main: 'Clear', description: 'clear sky', icon: '01d' } ],
  'stations',
  {
    temp: 282.55,
    feels_like: 281.86,
    temp_min: 280.37,
    temp_max: 284.26,
    pressure: 1023,
    humidity: 100
  },
  16093,
  { speed: 1.5, deg: 350 },
  { all: 1 },
  1560350645,
  {
    type: 1,
    id: 5122,
    message: 0.0139,
    country: 'US',
    sunrise: 1560343627,
    sunset: 1560396563
  },
  -25200,
  420006353,
  'Mountain View',
  200
]
```

I want to fetch icon property, so I tried this

```
for (let i in result) {
    if (i == 1) {
        console.log(result[i]['icon']);
    }
}
```

But I got "undefined" as an output.
please help me access the icon property in this array.

Comment: `result[1][0].icon` Simple

Comment: `for...in...` is for objects. `result` is an array.

Comment: Do you have multiple icons?

Comment: BTW ... how the array is filled is pretty unusual. The `result` items look like they are originally the values of an object's properties. Thus, if the object was known one hypothetically could write `obj.<propertyName>[0].icon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to use `for..in` with arrays. As `result` is an array, then you can use `index` to fetch the `icon` property as:

```
result[1][0].icon
```

```js
let result = [
  { lon: -122.08, lat: 37.39 },
  [{ id: 800, main: "Clear", description: "clear sky", icon: "01d" }],
  "stations",
  {
    temp: 282.55,
    feels_like: 281.86,
    temp_min: 280.37,
    temp_max: 284.26,
    pressure: 1023,
    humidity: 100,
  },
  16093,
  { speed: 1.5, deg: 350 },
  { all: 1 },
  1560350645,
  {
    type: 1,
    id: 5122,
    message: 0.0139,
    country: "US",
    sunrise: 1560343627,
    sunset: 1560396563,
  },
  -25200,
  420006353,
  "Mountain View",
  200,
];

const res = result[1][0].icon;

console.log(res);
```